# Fade out Animation Looped

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem that when I click on my button which is responsible for the fade in and fade out of of my view that the fade out animation is not working properly, the view appears again.

The View is sett in the xib file to a alpha value of "0"

my code:

```
-(IBAction)startFade:(UIButton*)sender{
    UIView *searchView = [UIView safe_cast:[self.view viewWithName:@"searchField"]];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        [searchView setAlpha:0.f];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            [searchView setAlpha:1.f];
        } completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd animation is in the completion handler of the first one, so it will do both animations each time, you would need to separate the 2nd one out

try something like this instead

```
-(IBAction)startFade:(UIButton*)sender{
    UIView *searchView = [UIView safe_cast:[self.view viewWithName:@"searchField"]];
    //assuming searchView.alpha == 1 or 0 by default
    CGFloat alpha = searchView.alpha;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        [searchView setAlpha:1.0f - alpha];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

this should swap it to hidden or visible with each button press

Comment: hey thanks for your answer but no that does not work at all

Comment: hmm might have to separate out the alpha value to its own variable, let me edit quick and see if it helps